# Populating combobox from app.config value

Tags: vb.net, app-config

Is it possible to have a combobox populate integers based on the max number from the app.config file from my VB project?

**For example** - I have this key in my app.config file.

> add key="Channels" value="2"

What I'd like is to have the combobox have the numbers 1 & 2 added as items based on this key.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So your question is "Is this possible?"

Yes, it is possible

Assign your key value into a variable and do it with a for loop.

Comment: I guess my question was more of how to do it if it was indeed possible. I've tried different ways of trying to read from the app.config but have been unsuccessful.